# Single column in GridView

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

How to make only one column in GridView like in ListView? For some reasons I can't use ListView. But I want to show my content in GridView in on column. So is it possible?

Comment: Most of the solution I found revolve you setting the Width of an DataItem to something greater than the (total width / 2), that way the Layout will not have enough left over width to make another column.

Comment: @ChubosaurusSoftware, it that's I want, thx.

Answer (score 0):

dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column name");

Comment: GridView doesn't have property 'Columns'. It is windows phone 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<GridView>
   <GridView.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsPanelTemplate>
       <VariableSizedWrapGrid ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
                              Orientation="Horizontal" 
                              MaximumRowsOrColumns="1"/>
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </GridView.ItemsPanel>
 </GridView>
```